# dotnet run on diferent port causes a "Connection id 'xxxx' request processing ended abnormally"

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, .net-core-2.2

Best regards.

I was working with an api app in .net core 2.2 and cors protocols and everything was going well until I change the port of my api from the default `https://localhost:5001` to `https://localhost:5002` using the `UseUrls` method on `HostingAbstractionsWebHostBuilderExtensions` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.hostingabstractionswebhostbuilderextensions.useurls?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Sending requests to the api throught `curl https://localhost:5002/api/values` still works, this means the use of `UseUrls` method is causing the cors validations can't works properly? Do I need an extra configuration method?

Program.cs

```
namespace api {

  public class Program {

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
      CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
/*===>*/.UseUrls("https://localhost:5002", "http://localhost:5003")
        .Build()
        .Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
      WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>();
  }
}
```

The console log:

```
Now listening on: https://localhost:5002

Now listening on: http://localhost:5003

Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[20]

      Connection id "0HLQOL2OADVUQ" request processing ended abnormally.

System.IO.IOException: The decryption operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Error desconocido al procesar el certificado
```

Answer (score 0):

> System.IO.IOException: The decryption operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Error desconocido al procesar el certificado

This is a certificate error. As you are accessing it over `HTTPS` and on a different port.

When Kestrel or HTTP.sys is used as a public-facing edge server, Kestrel or HTTP.sys must be configured to listen on both:

- The secure port where the client is redirected (typically, 443 in
  production and 5001 in development).

You need to add following in your `Startup.cs`

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

And in your `appsettings.json`

```
{
"https_port": 5002, // whatever you like to use
}
```

More [info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: Well, the `UseHttpsRedirection` method was already there in my `Startup.cs` so I just add the `https_port` value to the json file but the console displays the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Actually I was testing using Firefox which takes very seriously the  https certificates (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-does-your-connection-is-not-secure-mean) Every time I change the port of my api, I have to access to the api url from Firefox to allow its being used, otherwise my front end app (which is using axios) will fails without giving me any explanation.